# Is maple syrup a food under US customs law?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

I was bringing maple syrup from Canada to US, and I didn't know whether I should declare it as food. (US customs needed me to declare food, but not drinks). At the end it didn't really matter much, but out of curiosity - is maple syrup a food? Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you drink maple syrup?

Comment: @dan1111 I've seen people inhale it ;)

Comment: @dan1111 do you eat it?

Comment: For customs purposes, drinks ***are*** food, unless, perhaps, they are alcoholic drinks, in which case they are treated somewhat differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CBP [has a page on what the US accepts](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1273/kw/mailing+maple+syrup+canada/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ2MTMwNDQxMy9zaWQvT2hpb1pET20%3D/suggested/1):

> You may bring bakery items and most cheeses into the United States. As
>   a general rule, condiments, vinegars, oils, packaged spices, honey,
>   **maple syrup**, coffee, fish, tea, and baby formula are admissible.

and is classified as general food.

Comment: And remember, even though it may be allowed, you still need to declare it.

Comment: Yep, definitely need to declare it on the customs form, since you need to declare all the food!